# Can a cryptographic hash algorithm be used as a PRNG?

Tags: hash, random, prng

Can MD5/SHA256/SHA512, etc., be used as a PRNG? E.g., given an integer seed, is the pseudo-code:

```
random_number = truncate_to_desired_range(
    sha512( seed.toString() + ',' + i.toString() )
```

…a decent PRNG? (`i` is an increasing integer, e.g., the outputs are:

```
convert(sha512("<seed>,0"))
convert(sha512("<seed>,1"))
convert(sha512("<seed>,2"))
convert(sha512("<seed>,3"))
…
```

"Decent", in the context of this question, refers only to the distribution of the output: is the output of cryptographic hash functions uniform, when used this way? (Though I suppose it would depend on the hash function, all cryptographic hashes should also have uniform output, right?)

**Note:** I will concede that this is going to be a slow PRNG, compared to say Mersenne-Twister, due to the use of a cryptographic hash. I'm not interested in speed, and I'm not interested in the result being secure — just that the distribution is correct.

In my particular use case, I'm looking for something similar to [XKCD's geohashing](http://xkcd.com/426/), in that it is easily implemented by distributed parties, who will all arrive at the same answer. Mersenne-Twister can be substituted, but it less available in many target languages. (Some languages lack it entirely, some lack access to the raw U32 output of it, etc. SHA512 is either built in, or easily available.)

Comment: If your seed is only a 32 bit integer, it's not that difficult to bruteforce all of the possible seed values.

Comment: @Blender: I'm not particularly worried about security. (It's not being used in a security context.) But yes, given a small seed, I agree. Let's assume I'm using a seed large enough to handle all outputs. (In my particular use case, there will be ~600 outputs over the next hundred years…)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the cryptographic hash function meets its design goals, the output will (provably) follow a uniform distribution over its period, as every input to the hash function is unique by design.

One of the goals of a hash function is to approximate a random oracle, that is, for any two distinct inputs A and B, the outputs H(A) and H(B) should (for a true random oracle) be uncorrelated. Hash functions get pretty close to  that, but of course weaknesses creep in with time and cryptanalysis.

That said, cryptographic primitives are essentially the best mathematical algorithms we have available when it comes to quality, therefore it is safe to say that if they cannot solve your problem, *nothing* will.

Comment: As noted in the question, security is not a concern. Distribution is. Nothing in the question is limiting the seed to 32-bit: I expect that the output space is constrained by the seed, so let's assume I use a large enough seed.

Comment: In that case, yes, the output will trivially be uniform in the random oracle model (and also in the standard model based on the avalanche criterion).

Comment: Essentially, one of the goals of these types of functions is to precisely approximate a random oracle, so based on this assumption, they will produce two uncorrelated outputs for any two distinct inputs (in the *random oracle model*). But one cannot help but wonder what you need such a high level of quality for - cryptographic primitives are pretty much the top of the line, if they cannot be used to solve your problem, nothing will, really.

Comment: It's an easy function to call that is easily callable, and thus the output from the function can be calculated without the use of a central server. (Think XKCD's geohashing) Other algos, such as MT, would have worked, but are less available. It's modeled after geohashing. Your last comment, I think, nails it: mind putting that in your answer?

Comment: @Thanatos Done. A cryptographic hash function is certainly useful for geohashing when you have particular quality needs rather than performance or security in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It can be made to work (with good sized inputs, padding, etc. as mentioned in other answers/comments) and will provide reasonably good results, but it's going to be *slow*, so don't do that if you are doing simulations or something that require heavy PRNG use...